# How do I give credit for someone elses answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-format

I have just a answered a question because I knew where the information was (it was part of a response to another question authored by someone else).   I gave the credit to that user by creating a link.  Is this the correct way to give credit?

Please note that I did not include the complete link to older answer as I thought it may have confused the person asking the new question (he was asking something specific).

This the question I answered: [What are the criteria for a user background to become login background on user selection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123721/what-are-the-criteria-for-a-user-background-to-become-login-background-on-user-s)

Comment: Could you provide the link to the question you answered so we can review it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that giving credit by linking the answer that you used in creating your answer is the correct way. This could look like

> This answer is partly based on [some link].

Note that you linked the user and not the answer that you used in the answer you refer to.

Comment: Crediting the place where the information is, not the place where the bio of the user is is certainly more useful.